# Is there a way to prevent child elements inheriting event handlers in XAML & C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, eventhandler

World,

I'm fairly new to WPF and am trying to embed a TabControl within another TabControl.  My issue is that the child TC (with NO SelectionChanged handler defined) is triggering the parent's SelectionChanged handler.

I don't care about the child's TabControl selection, and although I could just add in a new handler for the child with `e.handled = true`, this seems like a workaround (albeit small) for inherited behaviour that I neither configured nor wanted.

Am I missing something?

I can't set `SelectionChanged=""` or `SelectionChanged="null"` - Is there a "proper" way to avoid event handler inheritance in XAML?

Using the snippets below, the parent's handler is triggered by changing the child tab selection.

XAML:

```xml
<TabControl Name="ParentTab" SelectionChanged="ParentTabSelectionChangedHandler">
    <TabItem Header="TabItem1" />
    <TabItem Header="TabItem2">
        <TabControl Name="ChildTab" TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <TabItem Header="TabItem3" />
            <TabItem Header="TabItem4" />
        </TabControl>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

C#

```
private void ParentTabSelectionChangedHandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print("Sent from " + (sender as TabControl).Name);    
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: The way almost all commercial teams work with wpf is mvvm. Bind a collection of viewmodels to items source of the table trolley and template into views.

Comment: Inheritance has nothing to do with it.
This is the built-in behavior of RoutedEvent - they bubble or dip through the visual tree and any element along the way can handle them.
There are two ways to solve this.
First, stop further ascent - this is what you showed.
Second, compare source with e.OriginalSource.

Comment: Yes you can... Look for bubbling and tunneling of WPF events in google.

Comment: From what I've read, I thought bubbling was the event being passed up (towards parents, not children), so the child should not receive the parent's event.  Also, if inheritance has nothing to do with it, why is the child TabControl using the parent's event handler?   My issue is that the child TC is triggering the parent's event handler, even though it is a different TC to the parent and has no event handler specified.

Comment: You are right: The event bubble moves towards the root of the visual tree (i.e. from child to parent). But this has nothing to do with inheritance. ("Inheritance" is a technical term that describes that derived classes have all the properties, methods, etc. of the parent classes.) One way to solve your problem is to define an event handler for the inner tab control, and set `e.Handled = true;` in this event handler.

Comment: You can also bind selecteditem and act in the setter of the bound property in your viewmodel.

Comment: I know what inheritance is.  My problem is that the child TabControl is inheriting the parent's event handler, causing the child TabControl_SelectionChanged event to trigger the parent's event handler.  It just seems strange as this forces any nested Selectors uninterested in the top level event to explicitly catch inherited events just to do nothing.  Depending upon the application, this could be many lines of code put in place explicitly to do nothing.

Comment: In the above example, selecting TabItem3 triggers ParentTabSelectionChangedHandler even though the parent TabControl (ParentTab) does not have its selection changed (it remains on TabItem2).